# How do you simplify the improper integral $\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1+x}dx$

Tags: calculus

Here's the problem:

> Determine whether the improper integral $\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1+x}dx$ diverges or converges.

Here comes my attempt:

**Solution:**

We have:
$\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1+x}dx$

Using the substitution $x = -t$, we get:

$-\int_{1}^{0} \frac{\sqrt{|t|}}{1-t}dt=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1-t}dt$

This way, we have eliminated the absolute value sign. From here, my hypothesis is that this integral should converge, since the degree in the numerator is $1/2$, and the degree on the denominater is $1$, hence we get a "total" degree of $-1/2$, which would be an integral of the form:

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$

Which would converge in this case, if we would use the convergence theorem and the so called "p-test". However, I don't really know how to manipulate our original expression to land at an expression about equal to the one recently described.

I'd be glad if you could share any tips and even general ideas, since I often have trouble solving improper integrals, no matter how much work I put into these problems. It never really becomes easier.

Comment: How about doing $t=u^2$ substitution?

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral will be like this... $\int_{-1}^0\frac{\sqrt {-x}}{1+x}dx$. Then substitute $\sqrt{-x}$ to $t$. Then $dx=-2tdt$, and the range -1 to 0 will be 1 to 0.

Yes, your integral will be like this...
$$
\int_1^0\frac{2t^2}{t^2-1}dt=-2+\int_0^1\frac2{1-t^2}dt
$$
Then, you must calculate this integral: $\int_0^1\frac2{1-t^2}dt$.

Use partial fraction, then integral will be this shape : $\int_0^1(\frac1{1-t}+\frac1{1+t})dt$.

But integral $\int_0^1\frac1{1-t}dt=\left[-\ln(1-t)\right]_0^1$ diverges.

So your integral diverges.

Comment: Thank you, that's alot easier to work with I must admit. I made it a bit too complicated haha.